# Progres - split query output into multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, parsing, dictionary

In postgres i need to split the output of a column into multiple columns.

**Query:**

```
select id, response from table
```

**This is what the output is now:**

```
id |              response                                     |
---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1  |{u'vendor': u'can', u'unit': 40, u'zone': u'Asia'}         |
2  |{u'vendor': u'bottle', u'unit': 15, u'zone': u'America'}   |
3  |{u'vendor': u'can', u'unit': 20, u'zone': u'South America'}|

(3 rows)
```

**Desired Output:**

```
 id | vendor  | unit | zone          | 
----+---------+------+---------------+
  1 | can     | 40   | Asia          | 
  2 | bottle  | 15   | America       | 
  3 | can     | 20   | South America |      

(3 rows)
```

Is there a syntax/function i can use to parse the dictionary key/values column values into multiple columns ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're dealing with in your "response" column looks a lot like a JSON hash... and by "a lot" i mean "it is." As it turns out, Postgres has ways to deal with such things:

```
SELECT id, response->>'vendor' AS vendor, response->>'unit' AS unit, response->>'zone' AS zone FROM table;
```

This should work in postgres 9.3 and later. That said, it assumes your "response" field is always a JSON hash, always had (at minimum) all the fields listed (it could have more), and is not portable to other SQL DBs.

For more information about Postgres' JSON handling, see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html